# convert long to String -garbled String

Tags: java, hbase

I now want to query a record in HBase(online DB) to verify one of the function that I have writed.But in my company,I don't have the permission to access the online DB.So,I have to give the row key(String type) to Operation and Maintenance Engineer,and let him to query for me.

I have read the application code,the type of the row key it generates is byte[].So I convert it to a String.

```
byte[] result = consumeRecordRowKey.toBytes();
String resultString = new String(result);
```

But it seems like this，it is garbled:
[image]

It generate byte[] using defaule encoding type,so I use default encoding too.
The Operation and Maintenance Engineer saied that he cannot do query use this String.So, what can I do to solve this problem?

**Update:**
The consumeRecordRowKey.toBytes() do these things:
it merges two byte array,two byte arrays are:

```
byte[] array1 = Bytes.toBytes("2088301654230372");
byte[] array2 = Bytes.toBytes(9223370625843459807);//convert a long value
```

and **what is garbles is the bytes converted by long value.I want to know,how to convert long value to byte[] and get normal String from it**?

Comment: There seems to be multi-byte characters in the key in which case your default encoding might not help. You will need to use "UTF-8" char while converting between chars and bytes. Assuming consumeRecordRowKey is String                                                           byte[] result = consumeRecordRowKey.getBytes("UTF-8") // 
String resultString = new String(result, "UTF-8");

Comment: The code that stores that should really be using something like UTF-8, not the default encoding.

Comment: `Bytes.toBytes` converts a long to a packed binary array, which is not a character encoding.  Sounds like you actually want `Long.toString`, which converts a long to a unicode decimal string.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Why it is garbled string when I convert the byte array generated by Bytes.toBytes?

Comment: because its not a string -- Bytes.toString gives you a series of bytes,  not a series of characters.  If you interpret those bytes as characters, you get a random-seeming mess.  Some of the bytes may not even been valid characters.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you and the creator of the byte[] have different default locales. You should either ask him to tell you his default locale

```
 System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());
```

or synchronize your locales by updating your code

```
 string.toByteArray(STANDARD_CHARSET_OF_YOUR_CHOOSING);
```

on his end and

```
 new String(bytes, STANDARD_CHARSET_OF_YOUR_CHOOSING);
```

on yours.

Comment: Could you give us the byte[]s that comprise that String? What should that garbled output read as?